# It always shows errors in .argparse?

Tags: python

this is when  i try to run it at first with no changes

```
C:\Users\BILEL.MK\Downloads\video-object-detection-master>python main.py --detect_class DETECT_CLASS --voice_cmd --score_threshold SCORE_THRESHOLD --tracking_threshold TRACKING_THRESHOLD net_model detect_mode
    input args:  Namespace(detect_class='DETECT_CLASS', detect_mode='detect_mode', net_model='net_model', score_threshold='SCORE_THRESHOLD', tracking_threshold='TRACKING_THRESHOLD', voice_cmd=True)
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "main.py", line 238, in <module>
        if args.detect_mode > 1 :
    TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'
```

if I put the type of arguments "net_models" detect_mode etc 
like 
net_models type : int 
detect_mode type :int
score_threshold type :float
tracking_threshold type :float

```
C:\Users\BILEL.MK\Downloads\video-object-detection-master>python main.py --detect_class DETECT_CLASS --voice_cmd --score_threshold SCORE_THRESHOLD --tracking_threshold TRACKING_THRESHOLD net_model detect_mode
usage: main.py [-h] [--detect_class DETECT_CLASS] [--voice_cmd]
               [--score_threshold SCORE_THRESHOLD]
               [--tracking_threshold TRACKING_THRESHOLD]
               net_model detect_mode
main.py: error: argument net_model: invalid int value: 'net_model'
```

if i add :

```
args = sys.argv[1:]
mode = int(args[0])
```

this is the error i get:

```
C:\Users\BILEL.MK\Downloads\video-object-detection-master>python main.py --detect_class DETECT_CLASS --voice_cmd --score_threshold SCORE_THRESHOLD --tracking_threshold TRACKING_THRESHOLD net_model detect_mode
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 219, in <module>
    mode = int(args[0])
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '--detect_class'
```

the code/

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import threading
    import argparse
    import math
    import sys 
    #import pdb
    #pdb.set_trace()
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("net_model", help="faster_rcnn_inception_v2_coco_2018_01_28" )
    parser.add_argument("detect_mode", help="The detection mode: \
        1 - detect all objects \
        2 - detect a specific object \
        3 - track a specific object" )          
    parser.add_argument("--detect_class", help="The class to detect. Required when mode > 1")
    parser.add_argument("--voice_cmd", help="Enable voice commands", action ="store_true")
    parser.add_argument("--score_threshold", help="Only show detections with a probability of correctness above the specified threshold",default=0.3)
    parser.add_argument("--tracking_threshold", help="Tolerance (delta) between the object being detected and the position it is supposed to be in",default=50)  
    args = parser.parse_args()    
    #args = vars(parser.parse_args())
    #args = parser.parse_args()
    #parser.print_help()
    print('input args: ', args)           
    if args.detect_mode > 1 : 
       if args.detect_class is None:
          print("Error: You must specify a class to detect if detection mode > 1")             
       sys.exit(0)
    else:
        currentClassDetecting = args.detect_class
```

Comment: Could you please fix the formatting of the last section (Split into two sections, remove unnecessary leading spaces)? When this is fixed, copy&pasting your code is easier.

Comment: The first argument is often the program name, or the path used to get to the program. In your case, this appears to be what's happening, I think.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This is too much unrelated code. You need to make a [mre].

Comment: Please use `type=int` or `type=str` in your arguments.

Comment: if args.detect_mode > 1 :
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'     when i put the type of detect_mode 'int', if i put it 'str' => main.py: error: argument detect_mode: invalid int value: 'detect_mode'

Comment: `args[0]` is apparently not what you think it is. It makes no sense to call `int()` on the string `'--detect_class'`. What do you expect the value of `int('--detect_class')` to be?

Comment: i get this  , if args.detect_mode > 1 :
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'detect_mode'

Comment: That tells you that `args` is a dictionary. You need to pass a key to it. Perhaps you need `args['detect_mode']`. You seem to be trying to guess how the argparse module works. It might not hurt to work through a tutorial which steps you through a detailed example.

Answer (score -1):

- This is a because you compared a *argparse.Namespace* object with *int*.
- you have to convert argparse.Namespace to *dict* first using `vars(args)`, then get your values like this one `int(vars(args)['detect_mode'])`.

full code below:

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import threading
    import argparse
    import math
    import sys 
    #import pdb
    #pdb.set_trace()
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("net_model", help="faster_rcnn_inception_v2_coco_2018_01_28" )
    parser.add_argument("detect_mode", help="The detection mode: \
        1 - detect all objects \
        2 - detect a specific object \
        3 - track a specific object" )          
    parser.add_argument("--detect_class", help="The class to detect. Required when mode > 1")
    parser.add_argument("--voice_cmd", help="Enable voice commands", action ="store_true")
    parser.add_argument("--score_threshold", help="Only show detections with a probability of correctness above the specified threshold",default=0.3)
    parser.add_argument("--tracking_threshold", help="Tolerance (delta) between the object being detected and the position it is supposed to be in",default=50)  
    args = parser.parse_args()    
    #args = vars(parser.parse_args())
    #args = parser.parse_args()
    #parser.print_help()
    print('input args: ', args)

    # convert args from Namespace to dict
    """
    args_dict = vars(args)
    print(args_dict, "type: ", type(args_dict))  
    print(args_dict['detect_mode'])

    """

    if int(vars(args)['detect_mode']) > 1 : 
       if vars(args)['detect_class'] is None:
          print("Error: You must specify a class to detect if detection mode > 1")             
       sys.exit(0)
    else:
        currentClassDetecting = args.detect_class
        print ("currentClassDetecting:", currentClassDetecting)
```

- in order to run this, open your Terminal/cmd and run the following commands:

  1. specify only `net_mode` and `detect_mode`: 
     `python main.py net_mode 3`
  2. specify `detect_class`: 
     `python main.py net_mode 3 --detect_class 10`
  3. example if `detect_mode` < 1 : 
     `python main.py net_model 0`

Comment: Comparing a namespace with an integer would not produce "TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'"